# layout not adjusting with screen size 400*800 and 540*960

Tags: android

What i am doing is creating a single layout for all screen and using this layout by setting dimensions in values folder for all screen sizes and i my case screen size 540*960 is fetching 
values from folder values-sw360dp xxhdpi rather than values-sw360dp hdpi

Comment: Would you please! post Xml layout code, Even I create Single XML layout which always fits on all android mobile screens.

Comment: What's the screen density/model of your 540x960 device?

Comment: <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="@drawable/splash_page"
 >

Comment: 4.3 inch screen nearly 245 ppi pixel density